# Change color of top and bottom bars of GNOME 3

Tags: centos, gnome3, theme

I run GNOME 3.28.3 on CentOS 7. Even after setting Adwaita-dark (the dark version of the default GNOME theme) as the application theme, the top and bottom status bars are still light gray. Is there a way to change their color too so to match the Adwaita-dark theme?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue on CentOS 7, GNOME Shell 3.28.3: found that changing the shell theme via gnome-tweaks only gave me variants of greyscale gradients for the top and bottom bars.

For me, logging out and switching from GNOME Classic to 'regular' GNOME in GDM solves the problem.